# Problems with Jquery when trying to make automatic postback to server

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a problem with the server that my website is hosted on, it is a shared hosting.
 When a user i inactive for 20 min you get logged off and have to re-authenticate.
 But this is a problem for me, and since i cannot configure the server i have to do a "hack" so that i dont get logged off after 20 min.
And i was thinking that a good way to do this is by making a Jquery function that makes a post back after x minutes so that the user never is inactive for 20 min.
Here is the Jquery i have tried using to solve this.

```
var ping = setInterval(function(){
$.post( "/Users/NewProduct.aspx", function( data ) {
        console.log( data.status );
}, "json");
}, 600000); // 10 min
```

The problem is that the Jquery does not seem to fire.
 I have set the time down to that i dont have to wait 10 min when testing. And for what i know when the function i fired it should write it in the console?
 I am not that experienced with Jquery so i am not sure if this is correct.
 Any of you have an idear what i wrong?

Comment: before digging to problem , after 20 min users get logged out because of session time out or due to form autentication

Comment: The 20 min logged out problem is because the website is hosted on a iis server, and the iis server application pool has a rule that is logging out users after 20 min of inactivity. I have set the session timeout to 1 day in the website.

Comment: please see in webconfig for the  `<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="default.aspx" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="60"></forms>
    </authentication>`

Comment: i have also edited the webconfig to that the session is a full day. The problem is that the iis server is logging out the user after 20 min of inactivity.

Comment: you can change the idle timeout of application pool in iis

Comment: @Webruster no that is not possible, as i said in the top. The place where i am getting the website hosted does not allow to configure the idleTimout in the application pool of the iis server unfortunately.

Comment: ah got it, it would be clear if you can mention that it is a `Shared hosting`

Comment: @Webruster sorry about that :)